# Flutter firebase auth for desktop

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, desktop

I'm trying to create an app that performs a Firebase authorization on a desktop.
I didn't find any full sample code for this so I started by create a basic demo project on VScode.

As soon as I add the package `flutter pub add firebase_auth_desktop` (without adding code to the app), I get errors when I try to run the app.

```
/C:/Users/yvan_/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart(18,25): error G75B77105: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'. 
[C:\FDSTiming\Project\Flutter\app3\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]

/C:/Users/yvan_/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.10.1/lib/src/action_code_info.dart(65,15): error GE5CFE876: The method 'FallThroughError' isn't defined for the class 'ActionCodeInfo'. [C:\FDSTiming\Project\Flutter\app3\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'C:\FDSTiming\Project\Flutter\app3\build\windows\CMakeFiles\18de2b4c67371752531dc30d7008f913\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\FDSTiming\Project\Flutter\app3\build\windows\CMakeFiles\122a37675ed5a5d637290377de62a3e1\flutter_assemble.rule;C:\FDSTiming\Project\Flutter\app3\windows\flutter\CMakeLists.txt' exited with code 1. [C:\FDSTiming\Project\Flutter\app3\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.
```

The code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:firebase_auth_desktop/firebase_auth_desktop.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } 
}
```

And `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
  sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth_desktop: ^1.0.2
```

Any idea?

I managed to get rid of the first error by adding:

```
firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
firebase_messaging: ^13.0.4
```

But didn't find any clues for the others errors

Comment: Hi, for anyone who is interested in the official flutterfire desktop. please upvote for the feature request in the link below. thanx!

https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/46591750-desktop-windows-linux-macos-support-for-flutte

Answer (score 1):

The flutter firebase_core dependency currently not supported by windows platform.

[image: Check This]

Comment: Hi, for anyone who is interested in the official flutterfire desktop. please upvote for the feature request in the link below. thanx!
https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/46591750-desktop-windows-linux-macos-support-for-flutte